# CreateFile function with CREATE_ALWAYS Disposition

Tags: c++, file

I use CreateFile to initially create a file, with:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile (TEXT(fileName.str().c_str()),      
                  GENERIC_WRITE,          
                  0,                     
                  NULL,                   
                  OPEN_ALWAYS,            
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  
                  NULL);
```

If I use `CreateFile` again to try and create the same file again, should it not be an error?

```
hFile = CreateFile (TEXT(fileName.str().c_str()),      
                  GENERIC_WRITE,          
                  0,                      
                  NULL,                   
                  CREATE_ALWAYS,             
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  
                  NULL);
```

I would have thought because I use `CREATE_ALWAYS` that it fails if the file is already created.

Comment: Can anyone explain what the difference is between `OPEN_ALWAYS` and `CREATE_ALWAYS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CREATE_ALWAYS flag makes `CreateFile` to overwrite the file if it already exists. You should use CREATE_NEW to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE_ALWAYS will do just that, always create it.
CREATE_NEW will fail if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

No according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag CREATE_ALWAYS means:

> If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>   If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero.

So Function DOESN'T fail when files already exist, it succeeded, just last error is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.